# android studio стала грузить цп при написании кода

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день android studio стала грузить цп при написании кода.Если начать писать текст в любом классе в android studio начинается загрузка процессора 50-100% .
Intel core i5 9400f
RAM 8GB 3200GHz
android studio 2022.3.1
Цп стала грузиться пару дней назад,до этого не было такого.И даже при создании нового проекта проблема остается т.е. дело не в проекте!
работает все на
JAVA 8
мб стоит скачать новую версию джавы?

UPDATE:Переустановил Android studio проблема не исчезла!

Comment: настройки АС менял? что-нибудь типа живых подсказок или анализа кода на лету и т.п.

Comment: плагины не ставили новые на AS?

Comment: Вроде ничего,всё так же как и было,в настройки не лазил!

Comment: Я делал игру ,работающую на canvas и тестируя на sumsung m12 при помощи usb кабеля ,и при дебагинге пару дней назад фпс на канвасе было 80
а сейчас 1-5 ,но как только я вынимаю провод и отключаю телефон от компа(т.е. от ас) то фпс сразу возвращается на отметку 80